# PCF85063A enable second alarm register

Tags: c, microcontroller, real-time-clock

I am developing an RTC library for Nuvoton M031SD2AE MCU. I use PCF85063A. I want to enable second alarm. [In datasheet](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/data-sheet/PCF85063A.pdf) it's address is 0x0B.

This is the second alarm register.

[RTC second alarm register](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gJH76.png)

```
void set_second_alarm(void)
{
    uint8_t secondAlarmValue;
    I2C_ReadMultiBytesOneReg(I2C0,I2CADDR,SECONDALARM,secondAlarmValue,1);
    secondAlarmValue = (secondAlarmValue) & 0x7F;
    I2C_WriteMultiBytesOneReg(I2C0,I2CADDR,SECONDALARM,secondAlarmValue,1);
}
```

I tried to do something like this. Because datasheet says default value of that register is 1000 0000.However, I think it could cause error in future use when other bits get manipulated. I also get error because I2C_ReadMultiBytesOneReg function takes uint8_t rdata[] as parameter.

These are the I2C functions I use:

```
uint8_t I2C_WriteByteOneReg(I2C_T *i2c, uint8_t u8SlaveAddr, uint8_t u8DataAddr, uint8_t data);
uint32_t I2C_ReadMultiBytesOneReg(I2C_T *i2c, uint8_t u8SlaveAddr, uint8_t u8DataAddr, uint8_t rdata[], uint32_t u32rLen);
```

Basically I want to write 0 to 7th bit of second alarm register to enable alarm. However, I couldn't figure out how to do it.

How can I write 0 to 7th bit of second alarm register ?

Comment: If I understood well, what about `secondAlarmValue = secondAlarmValue & ~(1 << 6)`? This will clear the 7th bit from `secondAlarmValue` without changing the other bits.

Comment: I see now you mean "7th" considering the very first bit (bit `0`) as being "0th". So your code seems right to me.

Comment: But I can't do like this because I2C_ReadMultiBytesOneReg() rdata[] parameter.

Comment: Please look at the error message and try to understand it. If you need help, add it to your question by [edit]ing it. Most probably your call of `I2C_ReadMultiBytesOneReg` is erroneous and needs a pointer to a buffer to receive the read value. -- Why do you call "MultiByte" functions, if you only need to read and write one byte?

Comment: @thebusybee The problem is that function needs pointer to buffer as you said but I don't know if I can do the same if i use secondAlarmValue as secondAlarmValue[]. I tried to define it as uint8_t* secondAlarmValue but I got "invalid operands to binary expression" error. Also I don't know if it would be true if I define it as array and try to manipulate 7th bit.

Comment: I think you need to add a `&` before `secondAlarmValue` when calling `I2C_ReadMultiBytesOneReg` function. So it becomes: `I2C_ReadMultiBytesOneReg(I2C0,I2CADDR,SECONDALARM,&secondAlarmValue,1);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not shown the error message and the affected line. Most probably it says something like "you provided an integer, but a pointer to integers is expected." BTW, used as an argument, an array decays to a pointer to its first element.

Instead of the expected **address** of the variable to store the values, and to read from, respectively, you provide the **value**. In C, you get the address of a variable by the operator `&`.

Actually the multi-byte functions expect pointers to as many `uint8_t`s as the parameter `u32rLen` says.

So this is the corrected version:

```c
void set_second_alarm(void)
{
    uint8_t secondAlarmValue;
    I2C_ReadMultiBytesOneReg(I2C0, I2CADDR, SECONDALARM, &secondAlarmValue, 1);
    secondAlarmValue &= 0x7F;
    I2C_WriteMultiBytesOneReg(I2C0, I2CADDR, SECONDALARM, &secondAlarmValue, 1);
}
```

If you look close, I have simplified the clearing of bit 7. You can simplify many expressions with binary operators working on a single variable this way. Reread the related chapter of your beginner's C book.

You did not explain, why you use multi-byte functions. Please consider to use the single-byte functions:

```c
void set_second_alarm(void)
{
    uint8_t secondAlarmValue;
    secondAlarmValue = I2C_ReadByteOneReg(I2C0, I2CADDR, SECONDALARM);
    secondAlarmValue &= 0x7F;
    I2C_WriteByteOneReg(I2C0, I2CADDR, SECONDALARM, secondAlarmValue);
}
```

Final note: Please read the documentation of all functions to add a sensible error handling.